# How to limit the size of association in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have a grails domain class as below :

```
 class Order {
   String orderId = 'OD' + System.nanoTime().toString()
   Date orderedDate
   String itemName
   List bids;
   static hasMany = [ bids: Bid ;likedUsers: User,]
   static belongsTo =[owner:User]
  }

 class Bid {
  Integer amount
  User bidedUser
     static belongsTo = [Order]
  }
   class User {
     String username
     String password
     String emailId
     List orders
     static hasMany = [orders:Order]
     }
```

What I am trying to do is , to query for an order with bits with maxResult of 10 as like

```
 def critObj = Order.createCriteria() 
     critObj.list{
       eq("id" ,1)
       bids {
         maxResult(10) //Trying to fetch only 10 records
        }
    }
```

How can I load only 10 bits(associations) , is it possible? . Or My design of domain class is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
def results = Bid.withCriteria {
    order {
        eq 'id', 1
    }
    projections {
        property 'order'
    }
    maxResults 10
}
```

But please note that you have to change your `Bid` domain class to add the relation in the other way from `Bid` to `Order`:

```
class Bid {
    ...
    static belongsTo = [order: Order]
}
```

Comment: Good idea but I am trying to fetch list of orders with their bid's , I cannot show all the bid's in one shot show I want to limit it.Is it possible ?

Comment: I've added the projections to get the orders