# How to render list with limited amount in Grails

Tags: grails

I have these domain classes:

```
class Account {
    String name
    String uniqueName
    static hasMany = [roles:Role]
}

class Role {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [account:Account]
    static hasMany = [users: User]
}

class User {
    String name
}
```

And I got a user list from this code

```
def account = Account.findByUniqueName(params.uniqueName)
def roles = account.roles
def userList = roles.users.flatten()
[users : userList]
```

It normally works. But I want to render the users with the limited maximum list. I try like below code but it didn't work.

```
def userList = roles.users.flatten().list(max : 5)
[users : userList]
```

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100227/how-to-limit-the-size-of-association-in-grails ?

Comment: you are confusing GORM/generated api and regular groovy api here. `roles*.users` fetches all the users (not the fastest way either), then you call groovys flatten to get them all in one list. and next you attempt to use GORMs list (which simply won't work on a regular java list). if performance is no concern at all, then you could use `take(5)`

Comment: What cfrick said is your answer. If the ordering of the users doesn't matter, just do `def userList = roles.users.flatten().take(5)`

Comment: @sumanj  I checked it but I don't understand how to implement to my domain classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360825/how-to-use-createcriteria-for-many-to-many-relation-in-grails